# Fourier transform certain class

Tags: fourier-transform

Let $\mathcal{S}$ be the class of functions $f$ such that $\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}|x^m \cdot f^{(n)}(x)| < \infty$ for all non-negative integers $m,n.$ 
I want to show that the Fourier transform is linear.

Comment: We need to check $\widehat{f+g}=\hat f+\hat g$ instead of $\hat f(\omega_1+\omega_2)=\hat f(\omega_1)+\hat f(\omega_2)$.

Comment: $ FT[x^m f^{(n)}](\omega)  = (-i\omega)^n \hat{f}^{(m)}(\omega)$ and since $x^m f^{(n)} \in L^1$ we have $\sup_\omega |\omega^n \hat{f}^{(m)}(\omega)| \le \|x^m f^{(n)}\|_{L^1}$

Comment: @user1952009 thank you. So basically we need to show that the F.t. is in Schwartz class not linearity we use to ?

Comment: Your question is about showing $FT[S] \subset S$. Since $FT^{-1} = FT^*$, we have $FT[S] = S$. And the linearity of the FT is obvious.

Comment: Got it. Thanks again.